# Why does gpg --list-keys modify my keyring?

Tags: gnupg

I am concerned that listing the keys in my GPG keyring changes my `pubring.gpg` and `trustdb.gpg` files. I expected listing keys to be a read-only operation.

Would you know what the reason is? If there is no good reason, is there a way to prevent it? Taking the hashes of these files to verify their authenticity would make my job easier.

**Script to reproduce**

```
rm keys -rf
mkdir keys

gpg --homedir keys --gen-key --batch <<EOF
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 2048
SubKey-Type: RSA
SubKey-Length: 2048
Name-Real: Test
Expire-Date: 0
EOF

find keys -type f -exec sha256sum {} \;

gpg --homedir keys --list-keys

find keys -type f -exec sha256sum {} \;
```

**Sample output**

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `keys'
gpg: keyring `keys/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `keys/pubring.gpg' created
.....+++++
..+++++
...+++++
..+++++
gpg: keys/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key A492C6DF marked as ultimately trusted
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  keys/pubring.gpg~
a5791aee44c5496e11105a9ecd6d1dc41b64c19f3ad236a21ad854fe636dda3a  keys/random_seed
357de0c1a72450c653f6a1bd472bc50db975e4016644967cd49c3edcd416bdac  keys/pubring.gpg
f408c36e2f20bcd79da92ddbbb9866fa47bd5c1cfa1457b09a8a7560ac52f94f  keys/secring.gpg
854fa0608f4a3d8ff264c4720c4c6e3a72db9a37a6e28244705f6dd3cd954ebf  keys/trustdb.gpg
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `keys'
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
keys/pubring.gpg
----------------
pub   2048R/A492C6DF 2017-03-02
uid                  Test
sub   2048R/CBA76512 2017-03-02

357de0c1a72450c653f6a1bd472bc50db975e4016644967cd49c3edcd416bdac  keys/pubring.gpg~
a5791aee44c5496e11105a9ecd6d1dc41b64c19f3ad236a21ad854fe636dda3a  keys/random_seed
d8d723c224be6e54099305f18d6064758b05033698d64c7d6c591e518b6116ad  keys/pubring.gpg
f408c36e2f20bcd79da92ddbbb9866fa47bd5c1cfa1457b09a8a7560ac52f94f  keys/secring.gpg
7bb05436e0077fbe90f3407ebd90d62a6d2983c878de9bfc6bf44d6ae724cf04  keys/trustdb.gpg
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `--list-keys` for the first time, GPG implicitly performs a trust database check (because you haven't done one before). This also shows up in your log:

```
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
```

Checking the trust DB is not a read-only process. It will at least change a timestamp in the `trustdb.gpg` file. Here is what the check is for:

```
--check-trustdb
       Do  trust  database  maintenance  without user interaction. From
       time to time the trust database must be updated so that  expired
       keys or signatures and the resulting changes in the Web of Trust
       can be tracked. Normally, GnuPG  will  calculate  when  this  is
       required  and do it automatically unless --no-auto-check-trustdb
       is set. [...]
```

> Taking the hashes of these files to verify their authenticity would make my job easier.

Key files contain more than just the key parameters, they have metadata attached. It's not guaranteed that two files containing the same keys always produce the same file hash. Hence, instead of hashing the files you should `--fingerprint` the specific keys if you want to compare them.

Also, if you don't want to preserve your [ownertrust](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html#option-_002d_002dexport_002downertrust) settings (or don't have any), then there'd be no need to backup the trust DB at all and you could just delete the `trustdb.gpg` file (although it would reappear with the next check).

(I couldn't reproduce any changes for `pubring.gpg` when using your script.)